# Subset repeated measure data in R

Tags: r, subset

For the follwoing data set

```
ndat=data.frame(id=c(2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6),
                    vc=c("bl",'m0', "bl","m0","m1","m2","bl","m0","bl","m0","m1","m2","bl","m0","m1"),
                    yval=rnorm(15))
> ndat
   id vc        yval
1   2 bl  0.24033800
2   2 m0 -0.59292580
3   3 bl  1.13617080
4   3 m0  0.08219857
5   3 m1  1.37190692
6   3 m2 -1.24172726
7   4 bl -1.66812438
8   4 m0  1.66443525
9   5 bl -0.95858647
10  5 m0  0.93729295
11  5 m1  0.64848009
12  5 m2  0.57172027
13  6 bl -0.34740570
14  6 m0  0.15883881
15  6 m1  0.88409881
```

I want to make a subset based on the `id` and `vc`. Subset `id` whose `vc` has `bl`, `m0` and `m1` (all three). The data set should have `id` `3,5,6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'id' and `filter` where `all` of the vector elements 'bl', 'm0' and 'm1' are `%in%` the 'vc' column

```
library(dplyr)
ndat %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(all(c('bl', 'm0', 'm1') %in% vc), vc %in% c('bl', 'm0', 'm1')) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#     id vc       yval
#  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1     3 bl     0.984 
#2     3 m0     0.275 
#3     3 m1     0.952 
#4     5 bl     0.242 
#5     5 m0    -1.10  
#6     5 m1     0.0883
#7     6 bl     0.448 
#8     6 m0     0.631 
#9     6 m1    -0.967
```

Comment: What if I do not want 'm2', subset only for c('bl', 'm0', 'm1') rows?

Comment: @Uddin Updated the post

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done in next way:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- ndat %>% group_by(id) %>%
  filter(length(unique(vc) %in% c('bl', 'm0','m1'))>=3) %>%
  filter(vc %in% c('bl', 'm0','m1'))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
     id vc       yval
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     3 bl    -1.67  
2     3 m0    -0.380 
3     3 m1     0.919 
4     5 bl    -0.0556
5     5 m0     0.519 
6     5 m1     0.301 
7     6 bl    -0.641 
8     6 m0    -0.850 
9     6 m1    -1.02
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  ndat,
  as.logical(ave(vc, id, FUN = function(x) all(c("bl", "m0", "m1") %in% x) & x %in% c("bl", "m0", "m1")))
)
```

giving

```
   id vc       yval
3   3 bl -1.2185123
4   3 m0 -1.2469732
5   3 m1 -1.5304222
9   5 bl -0.6663611
10  5 m0 -0.3416479
11  5 m1  1.6521134
13  6 bl  1.0613095
14  6 m0 -2.4401063
15  6 m1  1.5964508
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
dt <- as.data.table(ndat)
dt[dt[, Y := all(c("bl", "m0", "m1") %in% vc) & vc %in% c("bl", "m0", "m1"), id]$Y][, -c("Y")]
```

which gives

```
   id vc       yval
1:  3 bl  0.6630808
2:  3 m0  1.2458904
3:  3 m1  0.1636613
4:  5 bl -1.3373699
5:  5 m0  1.1810268
6:  5 m1  1.1541949
7:  6 bl  0.4885174
8:  6 m0  1.0508925
9:  6 m1  0.6994416
```